# My AVD not booting it keeps loading help me out?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager, android-device-manager

My AVD in android studio is not booting or opening it just keep on loading it takes forever and I tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be working.
I am using Windows 10, 4GB Ram, and am using the latest version of android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be the ram of your virtual device is higher and makes your PC busy, so you can decrease the ram of your virtual device or download other virtual devices which doesn't take more ram .

Another option is to use GenyMotion , it is  a virtual machine provider  software that you can integrate with android studio easily, it's very fast , it's as just like an actual device , you can download it from here
https://www.genymotion.com/download/